# Difference between "vague", "unclear" and "ambiguous"

Tags: differences, adjectives

What is the difference between "vague", "unclear" and "ambiguous"? All three have the same meaning to me, so when should each be used?

Comment: and *nebulous* too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vague means that the information is lacking in detail - if you give a vague description of something, the listener/reader won't be able to imagine the subject with much precision.

Unclear could mean the same but also might suggest that the information is confusing, either as a result of poor use of language or perhaps through contradicting information.

Ambiguous is when something can have more than one meaning or refer to more than one subject and the listener/reader might have difficulty knowing exactly what it is you are describing.

Answer (score 16):

'Vague' is used where something lacks precision or detail, while 'ambiguous' is something that could have two meanings, or is open to interpretation.

"Where is David?" ~ "He is in Europe" is vague, as Europe is a big place and David could be in any of it.

"I saw David in my car" is ambiguous, because it is not clear whether 'I' or 'David' was in the car.

Comment: thanks roaring, your example are so clear to understand me.

Answer (score -1):

And, to add to Roaring Fish, "unclear" is itself vague. The other two are unclear for specific reasons. Some examples that are unclear without fitting the patterns for vague or ambiguous:

- David is in the zone
- David is where he should be
- David is in the process
- David is having dessert
- David loves dance music

These are not ambiguous, because they are not referring to something that may have more than one clear meaning, and they are not vague, because they are not providing correct but uselessly broad information: they are bringing in dimensions that are not even clearly relevant to the question.

Of course, if they are relevant (the "process" we manage defines two precise places or one large place), then they might fit.

Comment: I don't find most of those examples unclear in the slightest - "David loves dance music" is a very clear statement with little room for interpretation. The intended meaning of the sentence could not be parsed any other way. How could one possibly express David's love of dance music in a *more* clear way?

Comment: There's also a strong philosophical case to be made that 'vague' is also vague.

Comment: As an American, I've learned that in BrE "David is having his pudding" is ambiguous. :)

Comment: "David loves dance music" is vague in the context of answering the question "where is David?".

Comment: @ockham "David loves dance music," in the context of "where is David?," is a non-sequitur. Something like, "David is out dancing," is vague/unclear. The only way this adds to Roaring Fish's answer is that it is itself unclear.

Answer (score -2):

The difference between "vague", "unclear" and "ambiguous"?
Their difference is in USE ... 
But they all MEAN that something is not well defined.

Comment: But isn't the meaning of all words in English established by use?

Comment: If the difference is in how they are used, please give examples of how use would affect their meaning. See the other answers: please note that your answer should add to the knowledge imparted by those answers.